# How would you test a Scala.js library for equivalence of JVM and JS implementations?

Tags: javascript, scalatest, scala.js

I'm using Scala.js, and have written a trait that is implemented for both JVM and JS.  I'm using third-party JVM and JS libraries to implement it in the two sides, which *should* provide functionally equivalent results in the JVM and browser.  But, I need to write a test to verify that!

If I were just testing two vanilla Scala implementations, I'd know how to do it.  I'd write generators of the trait's inputs, and drive each function from those, comparing the results of each.  (I can assume that either the function results are booleans, integers, longs, strings, collections of same, or could be toString()'d.)

Is anyone out there doing this kind of testing?

How would I do this where one implementation is in Javascript?  Phantom?  (Can I pass a generated JS file to it, rather than simple JS-as-strings?)  Something else?

Comment: To be clear: This library I want to test isn't operating on the DOM.  It's purely a computational library.

Comment: What's wrong with simply cross-compiling your tests? Since the trait has the same API on both platforms, you can cross-compile the tests against this API. Or I'm missing something in the picture.

Comment: For a few tests, where I have hand-coded the expected results, I could do that.  For most, I'd rather validate that the results from the JVM and JS implementations are equal, without validating each is a particular value.  (I have a high degree of confidence in the 3rd party library used to implement the JVM side.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Scala's [reflective toolbox](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/scala-compiler/#scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox) in a macro to execute your test code at compilation time (on the JVM). You can then use the result and generate code that compares the value.

So we want to write a macro, that given the following code:

```
FuncTest.test { (1.0).toString }
```

Can generate something like this:

```
assert("1.0" == (1.0).toString)
```

This actually sounds harder than in is. Let's start with a macro skeleton for `FuncTest`:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

object FuncTest {
  def test[T](x: => T): Unit = macro FuncTestImpl.impl[T]
}

class FuncTestImpl(val c: Context) {
  import c.universe._

  def impl[T : WeakTypeTag](x: Tree): Tree = ???
}
```

Inside `impl`, we want to run the code in `x` and then generate an assertion (or whatever suits the test framework you use):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

def impl[T : WeakTypeTag](x: Tree): Tree = {
  // Make a tool box (runtime compiler and evaluater)
  val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val toolBox = mirror.mkToolBox()

  // Import trees from compile time to runtime universe
  val importer = ru.mkImporter(c.universe)
  val tree = toolBox.untypecheck(importer.importTree(x))

  // Evaluate expression and make a literal tree
  val result = toolBox.eval(tree)
  val resultTree = reifyLiteral(result)

  // Emit assertion
  q"assert($x == $resultTree)"
}
```

The only problem we have, is `reifyLiteral`. It basically is supposed to take an arbitrary value and create a literal out of it. This is hard / impossible in general. However, it is very easy for some basic values (primitives, strings, etc.):

```
/** Creates a literal tree out of a value (if possible) */
private def reifyLiteral(x: Any): Tree = x match {
  case x: Int => q"$x"
  case x: String => q"$x"

  // Example for Seq
  case x: Seq[_] =>
    val elems = x.map(reifyLiteral)
    q"Seq(..$elems)"

  case _ =>
    c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Cannot reify $x of type ${x.getClass}")
}
```

That's it. You can now write:

```
FuncTest.test { /* your code */ }
```

To automatically generate tests for computational libraries.

**Caveat** The toolbox does not get the right classpath injected at the moment. So if you use an external library (which I assume you do), you will need to tweak that as well. Let me know if you need help there.